# C++ inherited operator not being called in the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have following code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A{
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int first(){
      return x;
    }
    int second(){
      return y;
    }
};

class C{
  public:
    float a,b;
    C(){
      a = 0.0f;
      b = 0.0f;
    }
    template<class T>
      C(T t){
        cout<<"Copy Constructor\n";
        a = t.first();
        b = t.second();
      }
      template<class T>
    C & operator=(T const &c){
        cout <<"Assignment operator\n";
        this->a = c.first();
        this->b = c.first();
    }
};

class D: public C{
  public:
    template <typename T> D (T t) : C(t) {}
    float area(){
      return a*b; 
    }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  a.x = 6;
  a.y = 8;
  C c(a);
  D d(a);
  D e = a;   // Here copy constructor is being called!!
  cout<<e.a<<" "<<e.b<<" "<<e.area()<<endl;
}
```

Here is the output of the above program

```
Copy Constructor
Copy Constructor
Copy Constructor
6 8 48
```

Why is assignment operator not being called in derived class?

**Edit1 :** I have changed the question to make the question more clear.

Comment: Better get a good C++ introduction. The error messages are pretty clear - you are missing a ; after the closing brace of `D`, and the inheritance of copy constructors is noted in every chapter about inheritance.

Comment: The error is on this code `D d(a);`. It has nothing to do with the `operator=`. @thiton: Why are you talking about copy constructors?

Comment: Correction made. Put up the wrong code here.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not inherited as regular public functions. Default constructor are defined by the compiler if missing, but you should define a constructor taking an `A` parameter (or templated as you did for `C`) for `D`. You will need an assignment operator to be defined as well.

```
class D: public C{
  public:
    D(A aparam)
    : a(aparam.first(), b(aparam.second()){
    }
    D& operator=(const D& rhs){
      a = rhs.first();
      b = rhs.second();
    }
    float area(){
      return a*b; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed. Note `D e = d` invokes the copy constructor, not the copy assignment.

Comment: @Alexandre: Thanks, actually both are needed

Comment: So if I already have a copy constructor then how do I create a copy operator?

Comment: @gibraltar: there is no such a thing as a *copy operator*, you really should read something about C++ basics.

Comment: sorry I meant assignment operator.

Comment: @gibraltar: your code already defines a (templated) assignment operator for class `C`, you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab back said operator= explicitly using :

```
using C::operator=
```

in D class.

operator= are inherited but masked by default by th eone generated by th ecompiler.

Comment: You'll need to do something else in this case, since `C::operator=`'s return type is `C&`, not `D&`.

Comment: if D inherits from C, then a D& is a C& and polymorphism will apply if needed.

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't work to upcast classes, you have to specify a constructor or assignment operator for `D` taking a `C` parameter. See the error that gcc gives http://ideone.com/Y4bCj

Comment: your code demonstrates copy construction not assignment. This is the proper code : http://ideone.com/xIzg4 with the proper error. Now with using clause: http://ideone.com/DYGjL

Comment: I just find it to be a *bad smell* that assignment operator on a `D` objet returns `C&`. But yes, your proposed solution works.